# Link static file in home.html

Tags: django

I have a problem running a js file from home.html

For example, let's suppose I have the following files:

**home.html**

```
{% load static %} 
<head>
    <script src="{% static 'js/assets/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/chatterbot/chatbot.js' %}"></script>
</head>
```

**chatbot.js**

```
$(function () {
   console.log('running');
}
```

I am supposed to get the *running* message in the console when loading the home page but I don't.

**settings.py** has the static urls defined

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^api/chatterbot/', include(chatterbot_urls, namespace='chatterbot')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and the project structure

[image]

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You are in development? (runserver)

Comment: @seuling yes, I am

Comment: can you try check `staticfiles_dirs` in shell? `python manage.py shell` -> `from django.conf import settings` and check `settings.STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: it returns 'F:\\artemis\\static'

Comment: Also try to add `STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")` in your `settings.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

According to your reply `it returns 'F:\\artemis\\static`,

Then your `static` path is wrong. I guess your `BASE_DIR` is `artemis`. So your `STATICFILES_DIRS` is `artemis/static/`. But your real project static dir is in `artemis/artemis/static/`.

So you should change your static dirs to `artemis/static` or just add your own static path in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. You can simply add absolute path name, or using `BASE_DIR`.

Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) for more information.